# Dealing with python lists

Tags: python

I have this list

```
list = [name1,desc1,price1,stock1,name2,desc2,price2,stock2]
```

How do I change it to the following using a simple for loop operation?

```
list = [[product#1 name,product#1 desc,product#1 price,product#1 stock],[product#2 name,product#2 desc,product#2 price,product#2 stock]]
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be a list of strings? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: it a list that is supposed to group items using the name

Comment: so that you can have different products in the same list

Comment: Please try not to use multiple comments for a single reply. You still have not answered my question. This code is not going to run in an interpreter.

Comment: list = [Desktop Computer,3Ghz, 16GB RAM, 250GB Hard Drive,1200,10,LaptopComputer,2.5Ghz, 8GB RAM, 128GB Hard Drive, 15"Screen,1500,15] that is the list am trying to group it by the computer name

Comment: Try adding quotes around your strings, first. Also, your problem has nothing to do with the simplified problem posted here. You've _over_ simplified. You'll be hard pressed to find any use for the answers here. I recommend [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` and `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re
import itertools

l = ['name1','desc1','price1','stock1','name2','desc2','price2','stock2']

[['product#%s %s' %(k, re.sub('\d+', '', i)) for i in g] 
 for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x:re.findall('\d+', x)[0])]
```

Output:

```
[['product#1 name', 'product#1 desc', 'product#1 price', 'product#1 stock'],
 ['product#2 name', 'product#2 desc', 'product#2 price', 'product#2 stock']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use a keyword as a variable name so change the name of your variable name `list` and you can try this for every item in your list

```
for item in lists:
  for i in item:
    # your operation here for individual items
```

or you can just edit with one loop with an index number,

```
for item in lists:
  print(item[0]) # you can say item[0] is the product name and so
```